# JQuery Tidy Up Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using a bit of javascript to animate an a class within a div class.

```
$(".previouscontainer").mouseenter(function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'0px'},"fast");
  });
$(".previouscontainer").mouseleave(function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'10px'},"fast");
  });
$(".nextcontainer").mouseenter(function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'0px'},"fast");
  });
$(".nextcontainer").mouseleave(function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'10px'},"fast");
  });
```

Was wondering whether there is a better/cleaner way to write this?

Comment: You should include the related HTML.

Comment: There is no need for the HTML for this question

Comment: Just thought that `a.nextarrow` might be a child element of `.nextcontainer` and that `$(this).find("a.nextarrow")` could be useful... never mind.

Comment: @Stefan yes that's a good point. `$(this).find("a.nextarrow")` is not much quicker than `$("a.nextarrow")` but if it was a case of `$(this).find('a')` that would be tidier at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain them.

```
$(".previouscontainer").mouseenter(function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'0px'},"fast");
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'10px'},"fast");
  });
$(".nextcontainer").mouseenter(function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'0px'},"fast");
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'10px'},"fast");
  });
```

or use hover which takes both functions

```
$(".previouscontainer").hover(function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'0px'},"fast");
  },function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").animate({left:'10px'},"fast");
  });
$(".nextcontainer").hover(function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'0px'},"fast");
  },function(){
    $("a.nextarrow").animate({right:'10px'},"fast");
  });
```

Or you can go mad and create your own event

```
$("a.previousarrow").on('moveme', function(){
    if ($(this).css('left')>0) $(this).animate({left:'0px'},"fast");
    else $(this).animate({left:'10px'},"fast");
});
```

if you need to bind it to various actions that can't be in the same selector

```
$(".previouscontainer").on('mouseover mouseleave', function(){ 
    $("a.previousarrow").trigger('moveme');
});

$('#somethingelse').on('click', function(){
    $("a.previousarrow").trigger('moveme');
});
```

There are other ways to swing this cat. `.hover()` is the most sensible.

Comment: May I suggest an improvement to this answer: Consider "caching" the selectors to reduce load.

Comment: i'm not sure it would help